# How to add nodes to FireMonkey TTreeView at a certain place?

Tags: delphi, treeview, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am new to using FireMonkey forms and components in Delphi XE7. I would like to add a node at runtime located after a certain node in a treeview. For example, if I have the tree in the picture, I would like to add a node `TreeViewItem7` as a child to `TreeViewItem1`; how can I do that runtime?

[image]

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507828/how-i-can-add-nodes-in-runtime-to-a-firemonkey-treeview?rq=1

Comment: I've tried this before I asked the question but actually it doesn't really work this way. I get an 'Access violation ' error here 
 ' Item2.Parent := Item1; ' .

Comment: You need to show more code than that, for that error. Have both Item1 and Item2 been created, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first, you must find source item, by `myTreeView.ItemByText` or `ItemByIndex` or `ItemByGlobalIndex` functions, `Selected` property, etc...

Then create a new element and add it to source item.

For example:

```
var
  NewItem: TTreeViewItem;
  SourceItem: TTreeViewItem;
begin
  SourceItem := tv1.ItemByText('TreeViewItem1');
  if Assigned(SourceItem) then
    begin
      NewItem := TTreeViewItem.Create(tv1);
      NewItem.Text := 'TreeViewItem'+IntToStr(tv1.GlobalCount+1);
      SourceItem.InsertObject(0, NewItem);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: how did you get the ItemByText working ? I am trying this but it refuses to find my item and always returns nil. I have checked many times that the text is correct. Is there a trick or something I should do first ?

Comment: @GuidoG ItemByText works for XE7 and I tested it now, for D11. No tricks, just simple code. Possibly, you need to ask your own question.

Comment: @GuidoG , I`m wrong... ItemByText search only in top-level nodes...

Comment: That explains a lot. I already wrote my own function for this, thanks